# Lining up data in two seperate lists in Python

Tags: python

I would like to combine data from two separate lists into nice table..
I have already tried appending the data into a new list but the the list comes back empty or there is an error code.

My variables are:

```
x = ['a' , 'd', 'c' , 'b' , 'z']
y = [ '1' , '4', '10', '1' , '22']
z = []
```

What would be the next step in solving this?

I would like the output for `print(z)` to be:

```
a : 1 
d : 4
c : 10
b : 1
z : 22
```

Comment: instead of list try dictionary

Answer (score 1):

To print an output like that you say you can use:

```
for i, j in zip(x, y):
     print(i, ":", j)
```

Comment: Thanks! My original solution was close to this but I was forgetting the 'j' in the "for i,j in zip(x,y)/